# What does expanding a variable as "${var%%r*}" mean in bash?

Tags: bash, variables

I've got the following variable set in bash:

```
ver=$(/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxManage -v | tail -1)
```

then I have the following variable which I do not quite understand:

```
pkg_ver="${ver%%r*}"
```

Could anyone elaborate on what this does, and how `pkg_ver` is related to the original `ver` value?

Answer (score 13):

It is a [`bash` parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) syntax to extract text from end of string upto first occurrence of `r`

```
name="Ivory"
printf "%s\n" "${name%%r*}"
Ivo
```

> ${PARAMETER%%PATTERN}
>
> This form is to remove the described pattern trying to match it from the end of the string. The operator "%" will try to remove the shortest text matching the pattern, while "%%" tries to do it with the longest text matching.

Answer (score 3):

You will get everything from variable ver until first "r" character and it will be stored inside pkg_ver.

```
export ver=aaarrr
echo "${ver%%r*}"
aaa
```

Comment: The `export` is entirely unnecessary here. Environment space is a limited resource -- the more content you have exported to the environment (and thus copied into the starting environment for other programs your script starts), the shorter the maximum command-line length when starting new processes can be.